# I need help to blit as many squares as the length of a word in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a hangman game, I need to blit as many blanks as the length of a word. I'm providing the class that I'm trying to use. Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

```
class Blanks:
    def __init__(self, length, win, color = (255, 255, 255), top = 500):
        self.length = length
        self.win = win
        self.color = color
        self.top = top

    def draw(self):
        num = [(50, 500), (80, 500), (110, 500), (140, 500), (170, 500), (200, 500)]
        for i in range(self.length + 1):
            num2 = num[:i]
            print(num2)
            pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.color, (num2[:][0], num2[:][1], 20, 20))
```

length argument gets the length of the word.

Comment: @Rabbid76 List index out of range and it prints an empty list for some reason

Comment: @Rabbid76 Whoopsie... I was actually looking for a way to automate the position of my squares as well, since I wasn't able to accomplish that I had to hardcode the positions. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: I don't understand how you want to use the list. For example, what should the coordinates be for the first rectangle that is drawn? The second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `num2 = num[i]` retrieves 1 element from the list. The coordinates of a element are (`num2[0]`, `num2[1]`). Of course you have to ensure that the list `num` is not accessed out of bounds (`range(min(len(num), self.length))`):

```py
num = [(50, 500), (80, 500), (110, 500), (140, 500), (170, 500), (200, 500)]
for i in range(min(len(num), self.length)):
    num2 = num[i]
    pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.color, (num2[0], num2[1], 20, 20))
```

Anyway, I recommend to compute the position dependent on the index (`i`) of the element:

```py
x = 50 + i *30
y = 500
```

Method `draw`:

```py
class Blanks:
    # [...]

    def draw(self):
        for i in range(self.length):
            x = 50 + i *30
            y = 500
            pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.color, (x, y, 20, 20))
```